# Diagonalizing differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I would like to diagonalize the differential operator $D=-\partial^2_t+a^2$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions $x(0)=x(T)=0.$

So far I have tried to find the eigenfunctions of $D$,
$$Df = \lambda f$$
by considering cases when $\lambda>0, \lambda=0,$ and $\lambda<0.$ However, it seems like for each case, the only function that satisfies this is the zero vector, which isn't an eigenfunction.

Is this differential operator diagonalizable?

Comment: Is $f$ a two variable function?

Comment: No, it only depends on $t.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we are working with only ODEs, then we are essentially solving
\begin{align}
f''(t)-(a^2-\lambda)f(t) = 0
\end{align}
with boundary conditions $f(0) = f(T) = 0$.

We see that this only has solution provided $a^2-\lambda<0$, which means the solution to the ODE is given by
\begin{align}
f(t) = C_1 \sin \sqrt{\lambda-a^2} t + C_2 \cos\sqrt{\lambda-a^2}t. 
\end{align}
Using the fact that $f(0) = 0$, then it follows
\begin{align}
f(t) = C_1\sin\sqrt{\lambda-a^2} t. 
\end{align} 
Using the second condition yields that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\lambda-a^2}T = n\pi \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda= \frac{n^2\pi^2}{T^2}+a^2. 
\end{align}